# Authentication don't work after one day

Tags: hibernate, authentication, deployment, glassfish

I have some problem with my JSF application. When I deploy it in GlassFish server in Windows server 12 every things work fine until the other day when I try to login. I get "password error" (authentication in my application).

I'm using JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5, Hibernate 4, GlassFish 4.

This is my hibernate configuration.

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
     com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <propertyname="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fashionzeroDateTimeBehavior=
         convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <propertyname="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">
     true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
      thread</property> 
    <property name="cache.provider_class">
      org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider
    </property>
```

If you need any details just ask for please. I need a help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Check if the password expired or locked. Glassfish server logs will have some information on the authentication. Can you check and post here

Comment: the authentication is not for glassfish is for my application, i have a page for authentication, when i used after one day it gives me this error. but when i redeploy it works again :/

Comment: Probably application cache or browser cache issue